# Adding/Setting Component Link in Metadata Fields

Tags: 2013, event-system

I'm trying to add a component link to the Component link field of a page metadata using event system.  I'm not sure why but its throwing an error asking for -16 at the end of the link which is a component.

A ComponentLinkField.value is a Component so I just set that to the Component Object I have.

When I go to save the page.Metadata it throws the following error where tcm:7-12361 is the component ID.

Invalid context Publication specified in URI: tcm:7-12361. Expecting: 16.

`ComponentLinkField newCompLink = (ComponentLinkField)metadata[GetConfigKey("PageMetadataFieldName")];
                        newCompLink.Value = newLocalizedComp;
                        page.Metadata = metadata.ToXml();
                        page.Save();`

Comment: I figured it out.  It was my own bad.  It was not the -16 for component but my publication was actually "16." So I was setting the local page that was as 16 with a component link that was at 7 and thats why it was failing.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. It was my own bad. It was not the -16 for component but my publication was actually "16." So I was setting the local page that was as 16 with a component link that was at 7 and thats why it was failing.

Comment: It's all about context. ;-)